# ¿Por qué en el chat mi reputación es diferente a la que tengo en el sitio?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, reputación, chat

¿Por qué aparecen números diferentes en la imagen de mi perfil?

[En la del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/312024/triby) 2684:

> [image: En el chat]

[En mi perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby) 1549:

> [image: En mi perfil]

Y ahora que entro nuevamente al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106796/discussion-between-triby-and-scorpions) ya no aparece el número.

Comment: La reputacion en el chat es la de toda tu red, no la de un sitio en particular. Y la misma tampoco se calcula on line.. tiene delay...

Comment: ¡Perfecto, gracias!

Comment: @gbianchi pon eso como respuesta... antes de que llegue un moderador y te llame la atención ;)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en realidad le conteste rapido pero seguro esto debe estar en algun lado!!! ahora lo busco y lo hago bien...

Answer (score 2):

Más o menos la información que se muestra en el chat es la siguiente:

- Escribes un comentario de **una línea**: aparece tu nombre/apodo al lado
- Escribes varios comentarios seguidos (sin que nadie más publique entre dos tuyos) o escribes un comentario que ocupe **varias lineas**: Tu icono se va haciendo más grande y, a partir de 4 líneas, aparece la suma de toda tu reputación en la red StackExchange:

  [image: Flair]